# Проблема c импортом классов в WebDriverIo js

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Не могу понять второй день в чем проблема,начал учится автоматизированию тестов,писал все в одном файле по началу ,взлетало норм,после деструкторизации  кода  по Page Object PAttern  тесты падают с ошибкой на импортируемый класс,хотя делал согласно спецификации..require тоже пробовал ,не помогло ,помогите !)
   [image: Ругается на объект]

```
json file




    {
      "name": "qatask",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "start",
      "main": "index.js",
      "directories": {
        "test": "test"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "test": "wdio",
        "build": "babel src -d lib"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.7.7",
        "@babel/core": "^7.7.7",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.7",
        "@babel/register": "^7.7.7",
        "@wdio/cli": "^5.18.1",
        "@wdio/local-runner": "^5.18.0",
        "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^5.16.15",
        "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^5.16.11",
        "@wdio/sync": "^5.17.0",
        "chromedriver": "^79.0.0",
        "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^5.0.2"
      },
      "dependencies": {}
    }
```

Код класса

```
import Page from './Page'


class MenuPage extends Page{

    get homeMenu(){return $('#xp__guests__toggle')}

    get addChildren(){return $('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/button[2]/span')}



    open (props) {
        super.url(props)
}
}
export  default new MenuPage()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Собственно ,магия StackOverflow сработала как только я задал вопрос ))
Проблема была в настройках Babel в файле wdio.config.js

Настроил по спецификации  под Mocha

```
 mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000,
        require: ['@babel/register']
    },
```

и добавил в  файл babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
      ['@babel/preset-env', {
          targets: {
              node: 'current'
          }
      }]
  ]
}
```